# PyQT5 changing taskbar icon

Tags: python, pyqt5, taskbar

Im doing a pyhton project using  pyqt5 and I was trying to change the taskbar icon but I couldn't find how to do that.So how can I change it?

Comment: try with: `QApplication.setWindowIcon(QIcon("path/of/image.png"))`

Comment: I think this changes the window icon not taskbar icon